# How to prevent a using SL5 runtime for SL4 application?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I've installed SL5 RC Runtime. Now, when I try to start SL4 apps it uses SL5 Runtime! In project properties defined that it is SL4 application. When I start the application, right click and click "Silverlight" menu, then I see SL5 Runtime.

How I can define SL runtime version exactly? I need to use SL4.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The definitions you have control over mean "run with *at least* the specified version". Each later version is meant to be backward compatible and provide an exact emulation of the previous versions.

I am finding all sorts of issues with the release candidate of Silverlight 5, and you can only have one version of the Silverlight runtime installed at a time, so for specific development you may need to uninstall SL 5 and reinstall the dev version of SL4.

Comment: I.e. runtime of previous versions includes in new version? Correct?

Comment: Having looked at the source for the Silverlight runtime via .Net Reflector I see it is programmed to be backward compatible via a number of switch statements they refer to as Quirks Mode. It is one set of code with specific checks to make it behave differently under different requested versions. SL5 RC is not quite finished so does not run SL4 apps exactly the same as the SL4 runtime (yet).